# Strange characters in http response

Tags: java, json, encoding

I am using the following code to fetch SFDC data :

```
HttpClient httpClient =HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
String uri = "SomeSalesForceAPI-URL";
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
httpGet.addHeader(oauthHeader);
httpGet.addHeader(prettyPrintHeader);
httpGet.addHeader("Content-Type:application/json", "charset=UTF-8");
HttpResponse response = httpClient2.execute(httpGet);
String articleJSON = EntityUtils.toString(response2.getEntity());

return articleJSON;
```

In the JSON response I the following strange characters, that I see when that JSON is shown on my local Chrome :  `Â    â€™      â€¢` .  Please look at the attached Response JSON below. I have bolded the strange characters. Also, when I do the view source of this JSON in my local chrome I see this : `Â&nbsp`

Thanks.

`<p></p>  <h2>Welcome to GoToAssist!</h2><div style=\"float: right; background-color: #f5f5f5; margin-left: 0px; width: 200px; height: 150px;\">           <p style=\"font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; font-size: 11pt;\">Resources:Â </p>         <p>â€¢ <a href=\"http://support.citrixonline.com/en_US/gotoassistremotesupport/all_files/G2ARS010012\" target=\"_blank\">Remote Support Quick Start</a></p>           <p>â€¢`

Specifically, the `â€¢` and `Â` values

Comment: That screenshot is unreadable, and you shouldn't be posting screenshots.  Copy/paste the text and format as code.

Comment: @ Jim.  Please take a look now.

Comment: In any case, that is definitely not JSON, so you might want to find the correct url

Comment: @cricket_007  Please take a look now.

Comment: Question is full of 3 screens of garbage.

Comment: Your JSON string is perfectly valid, just has some HTML in one of the values.  http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @jsonlint   I think it is some encoding issue, not the JSON.  That what i am trying to figure out.

Comment: Try `UTF_16` encoding

Comment: @cricket_007  I did this :                                                                articleJSON = EntityUtils.toString(articleJSON.getEntity(),StandardCharsets.UTF_16)   but still same result.

Comment: Umm, maybe you also forgot to update `charset=UTF-8`

Comment: @cricket_007   I did :                                              httpGet.addHeader("Content-Type:application/json", "charset=UTF-16");                                                                                                         String articleJSON = EntityUtils.toString(articleJSON .getEntity(),StandardCharsets.UTF_16);        but still the articleJSON string has same strange characters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114571/discussion-between-navchetan-and-cricket-007).

Answer (score 0):

Probably some characters are encoded unproperly for utf-8.
I think â€™ should be ' and â€¢ should be "
Check your encoding one more time and try to use below method

```
EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);
```

Comment: I did this :  articleJSON = EntityUtils.toString(articleJSON.getEntity(),StandardCharsets.UTF_8);   But still same result.